# cordova build ios fails for a blank project with unknown error

Tags: ios, cordova

```
➜  ~ cordova create HelloWorld                                                
Creating a new cordova project.
➜  ~ cd HelloWorld 
➜  HelloWorld cordova platform add ios
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.4
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: io.cordova.hellocordova
    Name: HelloCordova
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.5
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving ios@~4.5.5 into config.xml file ...
➜  HelloWorld cordova build ios -verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/mobile_ci/HelloWorld/platforms/ios/HelloCordova/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www] to platforms/ios/www
Current launch storyboard undefined
Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.
Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "io.cordova.hellocordova" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/mobile_ci/HelloWorld/platforms/ios/HelloCordova/HelloCordova-Info.plist
No need to update build settings for launch storyboard support.
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "HelloCordova")
This app does not have icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/ios/HelloCordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared iOS project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Error
    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:29:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Environment

```
Catalina 10.15.1
cordova 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
npm 6.13.1
xcodebuild Xcode 11.1 Build version 11A1027
```

Comment: You need to open the Xcode project in Xcode and ensure that have a proper provisioning profile and team. Apple does not allow you to generate archives or distributable IPAs without a valid developer license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved with the help from the cordova guthub issues tracker: https://github.com/apache/cordova/issues/176

Short answer is: keep all the tools and dependencies versions in shape, some of them might not be compatible.